# How to add layers to existing Keras model using the Functional API?

Tags: keras

I am trying to use the Keras Model API for modifying a trained model for the purpose of fine-tuning it on the go:

A very basic model:

```python
inputs = Input((x_train.shape[1:]))
x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(inputs)
x = Flatten()(x)
outputs = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model1 = Model(inputs, outputs)
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

The architecture of it is

```python
InputLayer ->  BatchNormalization -> Flatten -> Dense
```

After I do some training batches on it I want to add some extra Dense layer between the Flatten one and the outputs:

```python
x = Dense(32,activation='relu')(model1.layers[-2].output)
outputs = model1.layers[-1](x)
```

However, when I run it, i get this:

```python
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_1: expected axis -1 of input 
shape to have value 784 but got shape (None, 32)
```

What is going on and how/if can I add layers to an already trained model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Dense` layer is made strictly for a certain input dimension. That dimension cannot be changed after you define it (it would need a different number of weights).

So, if you really want to add layers before a dense layer that is already used, you need to make sure that the outputs of the last new layer is the same shape as the flatten's output. (It says you need 784, so your new last dense layer needs 784 units).

---

**Another approach**

Since you're adding intermediate layers, it's pointless to keep the last layer: it was trained specifically for a certain input, if you change the input, then you need to train it again.

Well... since you need to train it again anyway, why keep it? Just create a new one that will be suited to the shapes of your new previous layers.

Comment: It's clear now, great. I understand this being applied to Dense or convolutional ones, but batchnorm and dropout don't affect the output shapes, so they can be inserted into the model, right?

Comment: Yes. But convolutional layers support variable input shapes for spatial dimensions (only the filters must be fixed). And since you're working with images (MNIST, right?), besides getting much better results you will also be able to do what you want if you use `input_shape=(None,None,1)`.